# Azure AD - Configurate Single Sign On for group

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I would like to create an SSO for a single application, but I want SSO login to be only for one dynamic group, not the entire tenant.

I see only two options:
Accounts in this organizational directory only (MyTenant- single tenant only)
Accounts in any organizational directory (any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - multi-tenant)

Is it possible?

Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: as far as I know, Azure AD doesn't have an SSO configuration to allow specific group users to use SSO but others not. Azure AD has the ability to [allow specific users/groups to sign in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users#update-the-app-to-require-user-assignment). Let's say you have a application which has Azure AD as authentication scheme so it enables SSO.

Comment: if we set the configuration like the document, I trust those users not in the group wouldn't sign in successfully, but it will also make these users not able to sign in your app even they manually enter username and password, so I'm afraid the document I shared is not what you want. Let's see if any other experts had good idea on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I agree with @*Tiny Wang*, there is no option in Azure AD to configure Single Sign On for group.

**As a workaround** ,  you can assign users or groups to the Azure AD application to sign in.

*Go to Enterprise applications -> Select your app -> properties -> set Assignment required as **YES***

[image]

Go to users and groups and add the group:

[image]

When I tried to sign-in with the **member of the group**, the user got successfully signed in:

[image]

When I tried to sign-in with the user who is **not the member** of the group got the below **error**:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Restrict Microsoft Entra app to a set of users - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users#update-the-app-to-require-user-assignment)